# Jmeter thread execution internal process?

Tags: performance, rest, testing, jmeter, load-testing

when i ran jmeter script , i can see the below logs: Why it is repeatedly printed thread group 1-1,1-1,1-1...1-2 ?? I understood that 1-1 means first thread group - first thread but it is printed again and again what does that mean in execution side??

2014/11/27 03:45:59 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 2014/11/27 03:46:00 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 2014/11/27 03:46:02 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 2014/11/27 03:46:03 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 2014/11/27 03:46:05 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 2014/11/27 03:46:06 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2 2014/11/27 03:46:08 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2 2014/11/27 03:46:09 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2 2014/11/27 03:46:11 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2 2014/11/27 03:46:12 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2 2014/11/27 03:46:14 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-3 jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-3 2014/11/27 03:47:51 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-3

I

Comment: Can you show your test plan ? what version of JMeter are you using ?

Comment: I am using jmeter 2.13

Comment: I am using jmeter 2.13. In my test plan I have started a thread group with 10 threads and it will ad 2 trgeads, every 5 seconds with ramp up time of 4 seconds. After execution the logs produces are as above. My doubt is what is the significance of Thread Group 1-1  printing again and again aroung 6 to 7 times. what does it mean exactly??

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand. Since you have only 1 thread group in your test plan, That is why your Log shows

- 014/11/27 03:45:59 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
  started: Thread Group 1-1 2014/11/27 03:46:00 INFO -
  jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
  2014/11/27 03:46:02 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
  started: Thread Group 1-1 2014/11/27 03:46:03 INFO -
  jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
  2014/11/27 03:46:05 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
  started: Thread Group 1-1 2014/11/27 03:46:06 INFO -
  jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2
  2014/11/27 03:46:08 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
  started: Thread Group 1-2 2014/11/27 03:46:09 INFO -
  jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2
  2014/11/27 03:46:11 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
  started: Thread Group 1-2 2014/11/27 03:46:12 INFO -
  jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2
  2014/11/27 03:46:14 INFO - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
  started: Thread Group 1-3

---

The first number represent the Thread group started: Thread Group 1-1, Thread Group 1-2, Thread Group 1-3 ..........

The second number represents the user.